# Problem with extracting audio from a video file (android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio, ffmpeg

I need to convert an mp4 (or any other video format) to mp3 or wav file. I am using C# Xamarin.Forms. Any library I used either doesn't work for me, or isn't compatible with android. I have tried using Xamarin.Android.FFMpeg and Xobe.FFMpeg. 
I repost this because it was marked as duplicate and I clearly stated that that solution isn't working for me. This is the post that was flagged as duplicate: [How can I extract the audio out of a video file? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572380/how-can-i-extract-the-audio-out-of-a-video-file-android) . Please, I tried it but it just gives me the "Downloading Video Converter" dialog with a progress bar when I try to run the code in the solution, Also, it doesn't even extract the audio so after the user waits such a long time, it turned out as a waste of time.
Thanks in advance! :)

### EDIT 1:

This is the code I am using:

```
private async Task<string> ExtractAudioAsync(string path, Action<string> logger = null,
            Action<int, int> onProgress = null)
        {
            List<string> cmd = new List<string>();
            cmd.Add("-i");
            cmd.Add(path + ".mp4");
            cmd.Add("-vn");
            cmd.Add("-acodec");
            cmd.Add("copy");
            cmd.Add(path + ".mp3");
            string cmdParams = string.Join(' ', cmd);
            await FFMpeg.Xamarin.FFMpegLibrary.Run(Context, cmdParams);

            return path + ".mp3";
        }
```

There are no exceptions thrown. When the Run method is called it just shows on the application the following dialog:

### [image: the dialog]

After that, it just closes the dialog and goes to the return line without even extracting the audio out of the video. Even if I run this code again it does the same thing, downloading it again.

### EDIT 2:

I tried adding the `-report` option but it just did the same thing and did not save any log file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: there are MULTIPLE questions similar to this that all have the same answer.  If you are unable to get them to work then you need to provide details about the specific problem you are having so we can help you solve them.  Simply saying "that solution isn't working for me" doesn't give us any useful information about what you are doing or why it isn't working.

Comment: Hey, I have added the code I am using

Comment: Add the `-report` option to ffmpeg command. Then look for file named similar to `ffmpeg-20200309-093408.log` in the working directory. Provide a link to this file. (This assumes that ffmpeg is actually being executed but this is unknown.)

Comment: I added the -report option and it, again, didn't do anything except the dialog (means there is not .log file created)